# How can I force a ContextMenu to close (WPF project)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, contextmenu

I have a ListBox with items, and have assigned a ContextMenu to it with three menu items. Everything is working fine except that one of the menu items launches a lengthy operation. I would like to close the ContextMenu from the handler, and maybe display an hour-glass cursor or something.

Can that be done? Or, should I be using a Popup instead? If so, how do I use a Popup in lieu of a ContextMenu? My assumption is I would have to manage it completely - placement and lifetime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply run your lengthly operation under Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```
private void OnSomeContextMenuCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
  {
    // Put long-running operation here
  }));
}
```

If you do this, the ContextMenu will close before your long-running operation begins.

In general I prefer this solution to explicitly closing the ContextMenu because it completely separates the UI from the command handling.

Comment: Hi @Ray
I have tried the above suggestion, but it does not works for me, Am i doing wrong?


Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(()=>
{
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in (treeViewAdv.Items[0] as TreeViewItem).Items)
    {
        _RunTestScript(item);
    }
}));

Comment: Now that we have local functions, how could this be written using that?

Answer (score 22):

What you want is:

```
myContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
```

Be sure to call this *before* your lengthy operation occurs. Depending on your operation, you may want to consider making it asynchronous by performing the operation on another thread - that way, you won't halt the application thread.

Comment: Ray Burns probably has a better answer for the situation asked about, but sometimes you just want to force a context menu to close for a different reason, in which case, this is the best answer :)

Comment: This does not seem to actually close the ContextMenu, until after the logic is executed for the menuitem's click event.